# Strange behavior for Map, parseInt

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript - Array.map and parseInt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262427/javascript-array-map-and-parseint)

I saw this example of strange JavaScript behavior [on twitter](https://twitter.com/garybernhardt/status/294874591120211968)

```
['10','10','10','10','10'].map(parseInt)
```

evaluates to

```
[10, NaN, 2, 3, 4]
```

could somebody explain this behavior?  I verified it in chrome and firebug

```
['10','10','10','10','10'].map(function(x){return parseInt(x);})
```

correctly returns an array of 10s as integers.  Is this an improper use of map(), a bug with parseInt, or something else?

Comment: yep, this showed up in related when I posted it, but not in the search results as I was writing it.  I have no problem with it being closed as a duplicate.

Comment: There was also another similar question recently (this week, I think). I was trying to find that, could only find the one I linked to.

Comment: This is actually the one I saw: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594699/map-parseint-strange-results?lq=1  I think the answers here have been better than that one, but the older one you mentioned is also very clear.

Comment: A workaround could be to create your own wrapper around parseInt, like this: `const toInt = (value) => parseInt(value);`. This will works as you expected. Then use it like this: `['10','10','10','10','10'].map(toInt)`

Comment: You can also use lodash's `_.toInteger()` function with lodash `_.map()` to accomplish your goal:  `_.map(['10','10'], _.toInteger);`

Answer (score 113, accepted):

[`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) receives two arguments: string and radix:

> `var intValue = parseInt(string[, radix]);`

while [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) handler's second argument is index:

> ... callback is invoked with three arguments: the value of the element,
>   the index of the element, and the Array object being traversed.

Comment: ah that makes sense, so the 2nd number is trying to evaluate in base 1 and fails and the rest will just return the index?  That makes sense.  Thanks.

Comment: The rest aren't strictly "returning the index", but it works out the same because any number `x` in base `x` is represented as the string `'10'`. Note that if you have more than 36 elements in your array of `'10'`s, you'll start getting more `NaN`s at the end.

Comment: is there a workaround to make this work ? thx

Comment: @VincentWasteels Yes, sort of. You may use `[...].map(parseFloat)` or `[...].map(Number)`. Both will cast strings to numbers in the given array. However `parseFloat` and `Number` work slightly different than `parseInt`: both will cast floats as well as integers, while `Number` will turn strings that start with digits and have other characters included into `NaN` (e.g. `10abc`). `Number` can also cast all space and non printable characters to `0`. As a string to number converter both work pretty well, if only you *really* need to use `parseInt`: then use anonymous function as `map` argument.

Comment: Correct answer but doesn't offer a solution or alternative.

Comment: @DavidPrieto please check my comment right before your one.

Answer (score 36):

`parseInt` uses the first two arguments being passed in by map, and uses the second argument to specify the radix.

Here's what's happening in your code:

```
parseInt('10', 0) // 10
parseInt('10', 1) // NaN
parseInt('10', 2) // 2
parseInt('10', 3) // 3
parseInt('10', 4) // 4
```

Here's a link to MDN on `parseInt`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt.

Comment: `parseInt('10', 0) // 10` doesn't really make any more sense than base-1. That too should've been NaN. But I guess in a language where null, 0, false, undefined and '' are pretty much the same thing, I can sorta get why. `if (radix) {...} else {...assume base 10...}`. So basically undefined and 0 are both falsy, so they take the same codepath

Comment: @kornfridge That's explained in the link under *"If radix is undefined or 0 (or absent)"*

Answer (score 5):

From MDN:

> callback is invoked with three arguments: the value of the element,
>   the index of the element, and the Array object being traversed.

`parseInt()` takes two arguments. The value and the radix. That means that the `parseInt()` function is being called with unintended parameters.