# Convert number to a reversed array of digits

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reverse

I've developed this codepen (http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/qZjojV?editors=0010) trying to solve the following JavaScript problem:

***Given a non-negative integer, return an array containing a list of independent digits in reverse order.
Example:
348597 => The correct solution should be [7,9,5,8,4,3]***

The function below apparently is incorrect as it returns ["7", "9", "5", "8", "4", "3"] - correct order but with quotes. How could I modify it so that it returns [7,9,5,8,4,3]?

```
function digitize(n) {
  var initialArray = (""+n).split('');
  var reversedArray = [];
  for (var i = initialArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    reversedArray[i] = initialArray.shift();
  }
  return reversedArray;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add parseInt to convert from string to number, since when you split you turn every integer into a string

```js
function digitize(n) {
  var initialArray = (""+n).split('');
  var reversedArray = [];
  for (var i = initialArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    reversedArray[i] = parseInt(initialArray.shift(),10);
  }
  return reversedArray;
}

console.log(digitize(348597));
```

Answer (score 10):

"One-line" solution:

```
var num = 348597,
    arr = String(num).split("").reverse().map(Number);

console.log(arr);  // [7, 9, 5, 8, 4, 3]
```

- `String(num)` : The **String** global object acts as a constructor for strings and "converts" the given number into string(in this case)
- The `Array.reverse()`: method reverses an array in place
- The `Array.map()`: method creates and returns a new array calling a provided function on every array element

Answer (score 5):

Even better, reduce it to two lines:

```
function digitize(num) {
    return num.toString().split('').reverse().map(Number);
}
```

The final `map` call applies a function to each element in the array (in this case the function converts a string to an object) - everything else simply converts the number to a string, splits the string to an array and reverses it.

Traditionally, `parseInt` would be used in the `map` call, but this gives rise to [strange behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528397/strange-behavior-for-map-parseint).

Comment: Why bother with `num = n` when `n` won't be mutated?

Comment: You are quite correct. I was testing this out on the console, and had to create a reference as a raw value wouldn't work (I didn't wrap this in a function call) - I simply copied it out wholesale. I'll make edits.

Answer (score 2):

Just split and reverse

```js
var num = 348597,
    arr = num.toString().split("").reverse().map(Number);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(arr, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your approach returns an array of strings, not numbers

Comment: The result should be an array of integers.

Answer (score 2):

It is a **simplified version** of many other solutions that you can see, to deep understand how it works.

```
function digitize(n) {
    let correctArr = [];
    let arrOfNumbers = n.toString().split('');
    let arrOfNumbersLength = arrOfNumbers.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < arrOfNumbersLength; i++) {
        let x = arrOfNumbers.pop();
        correctArr.push(+x);
    }
    return correctArr;
}
console.log(digitize(348597));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you care about performance, here is the one.

```js
var num = 348597;
var digits = num + '';
var result = [];
for (var i = 0, length = digits.length; i < length; i++) {
  result[length - 1 - i] = +digits[i];
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

For beginners who may want to see a clear format on how to solve this via plain English, this may help to understand it:

```
function reverseNumber(num){
    num = num + '';
        let reversedText = num.split('').reverse().join('');
        let reversedNumber = parseInt(reversedText, 10);
    console.log("reversed number: ", reversedNumber);
        return reversedNumber;
  }

console.log(reverseNumber(12345));
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to solve this is below.

```
function digitize(n) {
    numbers = n.toString()//convert n to a string
    arrayNum = numbers.split('') //split the string and make an array
    arrayRev =arrayNum.reverse()//reverse the new array made.
    newArr = arrayRev.map(Number) // The Number constructor contains constants and methods for working with numbers. Values of other types can be converted to numbers using the Number() function.
    return newArr;
  }


  Refactored

  function digitize(n) {
   
    return n.toString().split('').reverse().map(Number) 
   }
```