# What is .map() doing in this situation?

Tags: javascript

Using the Chrome Console, this is my input and output:

```
[0].map(Array);

[[0, 0, [0]]]; // output
```

What is happening here?

**EDIT**

The reason this makes me curious is because something like

```
[0].map(String);
```

Will return

```
["0"];
```

And not

```
["0", "0", "String"]
```

Comment: I assume because he always needs some Javascript WTFs in order to feel happy

Comment: Oh, it's just a less wtf-y variant of `['10', '10', '10'].map(parseInt)`

Comment: Another strange `.map()` behavior: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528397/strange-behavior-for-map-parseint In general, you have to be careful when using `.map()` with functions that take more than one argument.

Comment: Just do `[0].map(console.log)`

Comment: @Bergi `0 0 > [0]` \n [undefined]` #chrome60.0.3112.113x64 #osx10.12.6

Comment: @npst: Ahah. I just landed on this question because it was a "Hot Network Questions". I don't actively look for Javascript WTFs.

Comment: @EricDuminil npst's comment was directed toward another SOFer who was commenting about Javascript's occasional WTF behavior. The original commenter removed his comment and npst's stayed. What cracks me up is that npst still received 24 upvotes even out of context.

Comment: @Jacksonkr: Thanks for the answer. I think it went like this : I wrote a comment, explaining that seeing JS WTFs makes me happy I don't have to use the language often. Someone asked why I would look at JS questions if I don't like the language. npst answered, and the first two comments got deleted. It's funny his comment still gets upvoted, yes.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

The [`.map()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is calling the `Array()` function with three arguments, the value of the array element which is `0`, the index of that element, also `0`, and a reference to the whole array.

So it's like doing this:

```
var a = [0];
var index = 0
Array(a[index], index, a);   // create array with three elements
```

The array returned by `Array()` then becomes the first element of the array that `.map()` creates, hence the extra level of nesting in your `[[0, 0, [0]]]` result.

EDIT regarding your edit: when you say `[0].map(String);` that results in `String()` being called with the same three arguments like `String(a[index], index, a)`, but the `String()` function ignores all but the first argument, whereas `Array()` uses all supplied arguments.

Answer (score 38):

**Firstly**, `Array` could be used as a function to create arrays:

```js
var arr = Array(1, 2, "Hello");

console.log(arr); // [1, 2, "Hello"]
```

**Secondly**, `map` passes three parameters to its callback: the element, its index from the array and the array itself.

**So**, since your array contains one element, the line:

```
[0].map(Array);
```

is equivalent to:

```
[Array(0, 0, [0])];     // the element 0 in the original array will be mapped into Array(0, 0, [0])
```

Answer (score 6):

After you updated question. Other answers provide you info about [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

To answer why array and string differ look to constructors

String constructor accept 1 parameter [String(thing)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) while array [new Array(element0, element1[, ...[, elementN]])](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: It’s the same reason why `.map(Number)` converts every item into a number rather than returning something like `[3, 2, [4, 1, 3]]` for every item.

Comment: @Xufox yes answer is in constructors :)

Answer (score 4):

This call

```
[0].map(Array);
```

gives you the same result as if you wrote something like this:

```
[0].map(function (value, index, array) {
    return Array(value, index, array);
})
```

[Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function is calling [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Syntax) function with three parameters: value of element, index of element and whole array. This call to `Array` returns you array with 3 elements: value (number `0`), index (number `0`), whole array (`[0]`).

And this new array is wrapped in the original Array, because you maped original element (number `0`) to new element (array of 3 elements)

Note: You might be used to using only the first parameter like in

```
array.map(function (a) { return a * a; });
```

or using just two to get also index

```
array.map(function (item, index) { return "index=" + index + ", value=" + item; });
```

But you need to remember that `map` still provides 3 parameters you just ignore them in your callback function. That's also the reason why code like:

```
[0].map(String);
```

returns

```
["0"]
```

It's because [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) function care only about the first parameter and ignores other passed parameters.
If you call

```
String(11, "Some", "other", "ignored", "parameters")
```

you will still get

```
"11"
```