# Explain the shortest JS function creation using a key of an object

Tags: javascript

```
var o = {["k"](){}}; // {k: ƒ}
o.k();
```

Here you can see an example:

[image]

How `{["k"](){}}` is compiled to an object which has a key `k` inside which is a function?

Comment: Did you mean `o.k()` instead of `o.f()`?

Comment: Yes. I've fixed it. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
{["k"](){}}
```

equals:

```
{
  k(){}
}
```

Which is ES2015 short method syntax for:

```
{
  k: function(){}
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `["k"]` vs. `k`?

Comment: @tadman its intended for dynamic keys, e.g. `[key]:value` ( the usecases are rare but they exist) , if used with a string in it its rather a missuse

Comment: @tadman See [object initializers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer), in particular the part on computed properties. However, in this case, I think `{["k"](){}}` and `{k(){}}` are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks, it is hard to Google. Reference: [Object initializer - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)

Comment: Sure it's ES2015 and not ES6?

Comment: @ibrahim aren't they equal?

Comment: Im sometimes surprised by votes on SO. Thats my second best answer of all time based on votes, and i mean thats just 8 words :/

Comment: @JonasW. [**I know exactly how do you feel**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46230125/what-is-map-doing-in-this-situation/46230151#46230151).

Comment: @JonasW. right time, right place... :)

Comment: @JonasW. Take a look at my top-voted answers.

Comment: Spend 30 minutes writing an extremely well written in depth answer, 500 views no votes. Tell someone about their typo... 5 views 5 votes.

Comment: @tadman That's the reason for `["k"]` style: You could do `{["\""](){}}`. This creates a function named `"()` (very bad style!). But imagine a situation where you create object properties that are named by user input. Everything could be possible...