# Reifying call to "new Type()" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is there a syntax/API/idiom in JavaScript to get a **function** that instantiates a type, for any type?

That is, replace a call to `new Type(..args)` with, for instance, (pseudocode) `Type.new(...args)` so that I can pass the function object as a parameter?

I've tried using `const newTypeAsFn = new Type` on its own (without parentheses), but it still results in a constructor call instead of returning a function object that can be passed as a parameter and called later.

This is an example of what I wanted to be able to do:

```
const newStringAsFn = String.new;
[1, 2, 3].map(newStringAsFn);
// [String {"1"}, String {"2"}, String {"3"}]
```

I came up with a function that does that:

```
const newAsFn = (type) => (...args) => new type(...args);
```

That can be used like this:

```
const newStringAsFn = newAsFn(String);
[1, 2, 3].map(newStringAsFn);
```

Is there a way to do that without using this (possibly buggy) function I made up? A convention? Popular library method?

Comment: what is `[String {"1"}, String {"2"}, String {"3"}]`? You can do `[1, 2, 3].map(String);`

Comment: Personally, I like what you have here already. I don't think there's a "better" way but of course that's subjective. You might try asking on codereview.stackexchange.com, I think this is too opinionated of a question for this site.

Comment: @ASDFGerte That won't work for a user-defined class, eg: trying that with `class Foo {}`, would create a type error.

Comment: @ASDFGerte But you have to be [**careful**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46230125/) with that. Also `String(1)` is not the same as `new String(1)`.

Comment: Yes, i just didn't understand the commented line for the desired output and wondered if it was `["1", "2", "3"]` and just written in some chrome console shenanigan way. At the time i didn't understand what the question actually was. Also the being careful part applies to the code in the question in just the same way.

Comment: If I might ask... why do you need this? I can't think of the use-case for this at all, so it would be super insightful to know if there really was one.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir great tip on being careful with `map`. I wasn't aware it passed more than one argument to the supplied function.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans this might be kind of a dumb way to do it, but I'm type-checking a json response, and I wanted to write a function like this: `const isDateFromString = fp.compose(_.isDate, newAsFn(Date));`

Comment: yeah if schema validation is the reason, then something like [joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi) makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With all the usual caveats, you could extend `Function.prototype` with a getter property to give you the syntax you seem to want.

```js
// Your 'new' getter
Object.defineProperty(Function.prototype, "new", {
   get: function() {
     return (...args) => new this(...args)
   }
})


// Call it just like you show. It returns a function that invokes `new String`
const newStringAsFn = String.new;
const res = [1, 2, 3].map(newStringAsFn);

console.log(res);
```

The arrow function lets you use the outer `this` value, which is the function on which the `new` getter was invoked. So it calls it with `new` and forwards on the args.

---

You can also implement this using `Reflect.construct`.

```js
// Your 'new' getter
Object.defineProperty(Function.prototype, "new", {
   get: function() {
     return (...args) => Reflect.construct(this, args)
   }
})


// Call it just like you show. It returns a function that invokes `new String`
const newStringAsFn = String.new;
const res = [1, 2, 3].map(newStringAsFn);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: I guess `Reflect.construct` is almost what I was looking for, except I wanted it to be auto-curried and variadic. Your solution is great and fits the example, so I'm accepting it. I prefer not to monkey-patch things though. I was hoping a library like `lodash` would have a wrapper that does what `newAsFn` does and I just happened to not know how to search for it, but if there's nothing wrong with my `newAsFn` I guess I'll use that.

Comment: Yeah, `Reflect.construct` not being variadic was a little disappointing. If it was, you could do `Reflect.construct.bind(null, String)`, though it's a little long. Your function is fine. Only disadvantage is if you accidentally invoke it with something other than a function.

Answer (score 2):

I think the right approach is using your `newAsFn`. And to make it even safer, you can make use of some higher-order-functions and closures:

```
let newAsFn = (type, numberOfArgs) =>
    (...args) => new type(...args.slice(0, numberOfArgs));
```

So that you can controll how many args to be passed to the constructor on creation. Usage will be something like this:

```
let strings = [1, 2, 3].map(newAsFn(String, 1));

let newArray = newAsFn(Array, Infinity);
let arr1 = newArray(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
    arr2 = newArray("Hello", "world", "!");
```