# Array map and parseInt woes

Tags: javascript, string

Given the following:

```
> '10.0.0.1'.split('.').map(parseInt)
[10, NaN, 0, 1]
```

Why isn't the output instead:

```
[10, 0, 0, 1]
```

Despite the following holding true:

```
> x = '10.0.0.1'.split('.');
["10", "0", "0", "1"]

> x[1] == x[2]
true
```

Alternatively using `parseFloat` does give me the desired output; however I feel I am missing something crucial here.

**EDIT:** `'10.0.0.1'.split('.').map(function(x) { return parseInt(x); })` works as expected.

**EDIT2:** I am using the Chrome Version 26.0.1410.64, but this also occurs in my local copy of node.js.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262427/javascript-arraymap-and-parseint http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594699/map-parseint-strange-results

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look at the bottom of this link, at the "Tricky Use Case" which explains the `NaN`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

It is common to use the callback with one argument (the element being traversed). Some functions are also commonly used with one argument. These habits may lead to confusing behaviors.

```
// Consider:
["1", "2", "3"].map(parseInt);
// While one could expect [1, 2, 3]
// The actual result is [1, NaN, NaN]

// parseInt is often used with one argument, but takes two. The second being the radix
// To the callback function, Array.prototype.map passes 3 arguments: the element, the index, the array
// The third argument is ignored by parseInt, but not the second one, hence the possible confusion.
// See the blog post for more details

// Solution:
function returnInt(element){
  return parseInt(element,10);
}

["1", "2", "3"].map(returnInt);
// Actual result is an array of numbers (as expected) [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: +1, for speed and accuracy !

Comment: Thanks!
I knew it would be something like this, but wasn't sure the search criteria.

Comment: Great answer +1. The example you gave is exactly what was stumping me! I was wondering why I was getting different results on Chrome vs Firefox but that's because the behaviour when the radix is undefined is implementation-dependent. I now have a broader appreciation for why the Mozilla doc say "always specify a radix when using `parseInt`"

Answer (score 2):

Quick solution, use `parseFloat`:

```
'10.0.0.1'.split('.').map(parseFloat); //=> [10,0,0,1]
```

Why `parseInt` doesn't work as expected? Answer here: [javascript - Array#map and parseInt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262427/javascript-arraymap-and-parseint)