# A small strange behavior of map with parseInt in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, parseint

I want to convert a string array to int array using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function, but I find a interesting thing is `['2023', '12', '0'].map(parseInt)` returns `[2023, NaN, 0]`.

I have to rewrite to ['2023', '12', '0'].map(elem=> parseInt(elem)).

From the docs of `parseInt`, this function accepts one or two arguments. Maybe it's the root case.

Update: I found it's duplicated with [Strange behavior for Map, parseInt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528397/strange-behavior-for-map-parseint) and [map + parseInt - strange results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594699/map-parseint-strange-results).

See more detailed explanation there.

`.map` calls `parseInt()` with three parameters - the `value`, the array `index`, and the `array` itself.

The index parameter gets treated as the radix:

```js
parseInt('2023', 0, ['2023', '12', '0']); // OK - gives 2023, 0 radix here is become 10 because '2023', see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#description
parseInt('12', 1, ['2023', '12', '0']); // FAIL - gives NaN, 1 isn't a legal radix
parseInt('0', 2, ['2023', '12', '0']); // OK - gives 0 in base 2
```

Comment: of course `['2023', '12', '0'].map(Number)` would work correctly with the example values you have :p

Comment: @JaromandaX Nice and clean solution. Thanks!